# Spring binding. Как связать данные form:select с множеством объектов

Tags: java, spring, jsp

Есть класс News, у которого есть список объектов Category (наследует id от класса BasedEntity):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class   Category extends BasedEntity {

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

public Category() {
}

public Category(int id, String name) {
    this.setId(id);
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Класс News:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "news")
public class News extends BasedEntity {

@Column(name = "headline")
private String headline;

@Column(name = "content")
private String content;

@Column(name = "date")
private Date date;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "news_categories", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "news_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "category_id")})
private Set<Category> categories=new HashSet<>();
```

Форма:

```
<form:select path="categories" multiple="true">
        <form:option value="1">Политика</form:option>
        <form:option value="2">Экономика</form:option>
        <form:option value="3">Спорт</form:option>
</form:select>
```

Контроллер:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "save", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded", consumes = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
public void saveNews(News news, BindingResult result){

    newsService.save(news);
}
```

Проблема в том, что контроллер никак не связывает select с множеством categories.

Comment: Попробуйте поменять Set на List. Да, смешное решение, но мне когда-то помогло.

Comment: Если не поможет, приведите стек-трейс, пожалуйста.